# Multiple dll reference failure on nuget reinstall

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard-2.0

I am getting multiple `The referenced component <packagename> cannot be found` when i do a nuget reinstall for my project. There are no build errors and i have to manually delete the erroneous references from the project to fix this 'annoyance'. Does anyone know why Im this is happening? (see screenshot).

I am using visual studio 2017 and .NET 4.6.1 and netstandard2.0 is installed. The project type is class library and If i look in the bin folder, it seems there is an additional xml file for each erroneous reference.

[image]

Comment: Unload your project, edit the csproject and check if the packages path are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was part of a known issue with VS2017 and netstandard2.0. After stumbling across this github release note page and installing this package, it solved my issue. `NETStandard.Library.NETFramework`, link to nuget - https://www.nuget.org/packages/NETStandard.Library.NETFramework/

https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/2.0/2.0.0-preview2-known-issues.md#netstandard-20-and-the-net-framework

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.